# AC current generated from electromagnetic induced EMF is not sinusoidal. What is wrong?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I tried to induce an EMF by rotating a coil between two magnets, like so:[image]

I expected the output voltage to be a sinusoidal curve, but for some reason it dips back down at the peaks. I tried changing the angular velocity of the coil and the problem remained the same at every velocity. It looks like so:
[image]
Does anyone have an idea why the output voltage is shaped like this?

Comment: For one, you're rotating a square core around. Now, air is really bad for magnetism so the length of the air gap between your magnets and the core has a big influence. The air gap is smallest, 4 times per rotation. Every time when the line between the two magnets goes diagonaly trough the core... (which is interestingly also the position in which the rotation stoppend in your image)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that nothing is wrong. It just means that the magnetic field from your coil is has some higher multipole moments than simply the dipole moment.

It is possible that the sharp switching is an artifact.

Comment: That or there is a signed/unsigned data error in the path between the ADC/DAQ and the plotting program.

Comment: That is a good point

Answer (score 0):

A sinusoidal emf assumes a uniform magnetic field throughout the entire volume through which the coil rotates.  Your magnets are too narrow for the coil.  Peaks would occur when the coil axis is perpendicular to the magnetic field.  When this is true, Most of the coil loops are outside of the strongest part of the magnetic field.  I would recommend attaching metal disks to the inward ends of the magnets.  This may make the magnetic field more uniform in the space within which the coil rotates.
To verify this, place two bar magnets near each other with opposite poles facing each other.  Sprinkle iron filings.  The filings will be most dense in the space between the magnets, directed from the north pole of one magnet to the south pole of the other.  Magnetic field from the outer north pole will circle around to the outer south pole, actually opposite the direction of the magnetic field between the magnets.  Between the two zones, the magnetic field will be quite weak.  Use a magnetic field sensor to measure field strength as far from the axis between the magnets as the ends of the coil can extend.  As you move from that axis, field will decrease and eventually reverse.

Comment: If the disks don't work, would it be a good idea to redo the experiment with larger magnets (I don't have any on hand), or is there some way I can extrapolate the real values from this graph?